# $H,K\leq GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ such that $H\cong K$ then can we say that the traces of the corresponding elements of $H$ and $K$ are same?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

If I have two subgroups $H,K$ of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ such that $H\cong K$ then can we say that the traces of the corresponding elements of $H$ and $K$ are same? In general when is the trace of a matrix invariant?

I don't know how to mathematically argue for this. I would really appreciate it if somebody could point it out to me. Also, please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Please specify what $\mathbb{Z}_n$ means. Have you considered the case where $H,K$ are cyclic (or, for instance, nontrivial automorphisms of a cyclic subgroup)?

Comment: This is a good exercise in coming up with small examples. What are some elements in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ of order $2$?

Comment: @Aphelli $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is just $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Zackkenyon so it eventually leads to a counterexample and this means the trace won't be same in this case?

Comment: @AnishRay Write it up :)

Comment: If anybody is interested to know the final answer; it's no. The trace isn't invariant at least in this case.

Comment: With $n=3$, the diagonal matrix with both entries equal to $2$ and the diagonal matrix with one entry equal to $2$ and the other equal to $1$ both generate cyclic groups of order $2$, but have different traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Look at $\rm{GL}_2(\Bbb F_3)$.

Consider $H=\langle \begin {pmatrix}-1\quad-1\\0\quad 1\end {pmatrix}\rangle \cong C_2$.

And $K=\langle \begin {pmatrix}-1\quad 0\\0\quad-1\end {pmatrix}\rangle\cong C_2$.

Similar matrices have the same trace (though).